# Error - NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, menu, navigation, navbar

I am stuck with this : < a href="{% url 'newapp:home' %}" > revWaves< /a>

**Error message is : "NoReverseMatch"**

**Reverse for 'home()' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []**

I have created namespace for 'newapp' and url path is also correct i.e. /static/newapp/home.html and above < a href="{% url 'newapp:home' %}"> revWaves< /a> goes into header.html

So i am not able to figure out what is the error. Kindly help.

`Main Urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url , include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^newapp/', include('newapp.urls', namespace='newapp')),
]
```

`newapp urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url , include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.home) ,
    url(r'^about$',views.about) ,
    url(r'^services',views.service) ,
    url(r'^customers',views.customer),
    url(r'^contact',views.contact) ,
    ]
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def home(request) :
    return render(request, 'newapp/home.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'newapp/about.html')

def service(request):
    return render(request, 'newapp/services.html')

def customer(request):
    return render(request, 'newapp/customers.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'newapp/contact.html')
```

`header.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Ady Rules</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "newapp/style.css" %}"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<style>
h1.intro {
    color: brown;
}

</style>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- logo --!>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'newapp:home' %}"> revWaves</a>
    <div>
  </div>





</head>

<body class="body" style="background-color:#f6f6f6">

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}


</body>
</html>
```

`home.html`

```
{% extends "newapp/header.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h2>Hey There ! How Ya Doin ? </h2>

<h2> Welcome to the world of Programming !!</h2>

<h1 class = "intro"> New Appppppppp !!!!!!</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please update your question with urls.py also.

Comment: Hi Ady_bl, welcome to Stack Overflow. When it comes to asking a question, it is often best to include as much detail as possible. I would suggest including all relevant code to the area that you are having issues. Also make sure to format code where possible as well. Screenshots of the problem can also be very helpful!

Comment: Thanks Matthew & Abdul. I have added the code as well now.

Comment: Why you are not showing the actual code you have. My initial diagnosis show that the above code will throw `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: @RajaSimon, have added header.html & home.html also.

Comment: I think you did not defined the name of the url pattern. `url(r'^$',views.home,name="home")`

Comment: @AnkitaGupta, yes it worked. Thanks !

Comment: @RajaSimon, I am new to this platform. Thanks !